# Why is my ID not listed in the Datastore Viewer as a filter parameter?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Why is my ID not listed in the Datastore Viewer as a filter parameter although its indexed. I just checked my Datastore Viewer for newly inserted entities and wanted to search for a record by Email ID as a filter parameter but the parameters for the filter are the ones that I had put as @Index. Email ID was also @Index but it is also @Id.

Does anyone know, how can I bring the @Id param to used as a filter in the Datastore Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the actual `id` of an entity, then you can filter by it with the `Key` property

For example, let's say your `id` is an auto id (meaning it's a long int), and your kind is `example`. If you want to filter just for the id `562949953421312` you would put `Key(example, 5629499534213120)` in the key field:

[image: Filtering by Key with auto id]

If your @Id is a string, the premise is the same example surround the name by quotes.

[image: Filtering by Key with name instead of id]

Comment: The 'Key literal' written in the blank confused me. Thanks for clearing it up. I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: No problem. I'll flag it for our UI/UX teams toe review

Comment: No need. When I click it, it shows me the meaning of it with examples. I should have clicked it but like any blank field, you don't click it unless you know what to fill it with...that resulted in it.